# Cannot include a file from an excluded directory with .gitignore on Vs Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

I have a directory in VS Code which is excluded with `.gitignore` .
Let's name this directory `txt_files`.

In this directory i have a file which i would like to be included in my git thought. Let's name this file `file.txt`

This is what's my `.gitignore` file looks like.

```
#ignore /venv files 
/venv

#ignore vscode files 
.vscode

# txt_files_folder
/txt_files

# include this file
!/txt_files/file.txt
```

but when i hit `git status` i get no updates to add `/txt_files/file.txt`.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore a folder you do `folder/` but this will ignore everything within and not allow for exclusions. So what you need to do there is:

```
# Ignore things within txt_files (not txt_files itself)
txt_files/*
# But not file.txt.
!txt_files/file.txt
```

if you do the entire folder it means its children also get excluded regardless of exclusions

Comment: still git status shows untracked txt_files folder, not the whole path to the file

Answer (score 0):

If it is a singular exception that you want to track `txt_files/file.txt`, it is sufficient to

```
git add -f txt_files/file.txt
```

once. Thereafter, it will be tracked and any changes you make to the file will be detected.

(If you do not have a command line to do that, you can remove `/txt_files` from `.gitignore` temporarily until you have added the file.)

If it can happen repeatedly,  or there is a pattern of files that you want to add, you better follow [@code_fodder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57571844/6868543).